# Conditional distribution relations

Tags: conditional-expectation, probability-inequalities

There is a probability density function of the form,

$f_S(s)=\displaystyle\iint f_S(s|x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$

that is used for evaluation of expectation of some monotonic function

$\mathbb{E}[g(S)]=\displaystyle \int g(s)\iint f_S(s|x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdyds$.

$X$ and $Y$ are identically marginally distributed and the relation between them is one of the three following cases:

1. $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, i.e. correlation coefficient is 0.
2. $X,Y$ are correlated, $Cov[X,Y] > 0$.
3. $X=Y$, i.e. correlation coefficient is 1.

Intuitively, the relation between the cases is $\mathbb{E}_3>\mathbb{E}_2>\mathbb{E}_1$. Is there a convenient proof for this relation?

Comment: What are you holding constant in order to compare the expectations?  I'm having trouble making sense of your inequalities, given that the three cases are completely different situations.

Comment: Thanks! The question was revised and clarified following your question.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but you have only changed the notation without addressing the underlying problem.  In cases 1, 2, and 3, *the functions $f_X$ and $f_{X,Y}$ are changing.*  There is no basis to compare expectations, nor would there be any universal inequalities that could possibly apply.  Do you have a more specific question that you could articulate?

Comment: I would like to add few comments: 1) The marginal distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is identical (question is updated). 2.) Probably, I am looking something that may be in the style of Section 3 [here](https://www.stat.washington.edu/article/tech-report/andersons-theorem-integral-symmetric-unimodal-function-over-symmetric-convex)

Comment: Thank you (+1).  Have you given any thought to the case where the correlation coefficient is *negative*?  I believe that might give you some insight into why no such relation can be expected to hold.

Comment: This problem has physical base, with only _positive_ correlation possible. I have edited the question accordingly.